# How do you export the root trust certificate for a site, in Chrome on OS X?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, trusted-root-certificates

I visit some site in Chrome, and get the lock icon; clicking it, then "Connection", then "Certificate Information" brings up a dialog with several certs listed, the first of which is the root of trust for the site I'm visiting. **How can I find this cert, export it to a .crt/.cer (base64 encoded x509) file, and modify its trust settings?**

Additionally, I can go to chrome://settings/, click "Show advanced settings…", then click "Manage certificates…" which opens Keychain Access. However, *nowhere in Keychain Access do I see the certificate I'm interested in*, and Search cannot find it.

The cert is a bit weird: it is an corporate internal CA cert.

Comment: If it would be a coporate intercal CA cert it usually would give you a certification error "the certificate chain could note be veryfied" or something like "the CA is unknown and therefore not trusted". Please name the website and i will check the certificate.

Comment: It's internal; there's no URL that I can give you by definition. I only get TLS errors in FF, because the cert isn't in it's trust store (which is why I'm trying to export it from OS X's); Chrome verifies fine, and references a cert that I cannot find, hence the question.

Comment: If it is a coperate internal certificate it has to have a internal CA. You would need to go to that CA and export the root certificate and import it at your computer.

Comment: The cert *is* on the computer — at least, it is in the trust store that both Chrome and Safari look at, which my understand is Keychain Access. *Where* it is in Keychain Access (or in general, if that assumption is correct) is the crux of the question. (And it must be on the machine, given that both Chrome and Safari validate end-user certs signed by the CA cert that I'm looking for.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to view the certificate:

- in a popup in front of your URL address or
- in the DevOps Tool Security tab

Then, in the certificate dialog window, select the correct certificate in the tree (website, intermediate or root - not all might be available) and **drag the certificate icon** to a local directory on your machine (or directly in the Keychain Access app).

In the **Keychain Access** app, drag the certificate in the the **System** folder. Then you change the Trust options accordingly to your needs as by default probably it will not be trusted (hence you have the problem in the first place)